# discord.py: How to use Spotify class in a embed?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a userinfo command and I have an activity section where the activity of the user is being displayed. If the activity is `Spotify`, I want to display the title, artist, album and album cover url.

However, my code currently isn't detecting when the user is listening to spotify.

My code:

```
@client.command(aliases=['whois', 'user'])
async def userinfo(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member:
       if not member.id in [674381913867288619, 716031519667388426, 711978045774233690]:
            if member.activity == None:
                activity = 'Keine'

            elif member.activity == Spotify:
                activity = 'Spotify' \
                           f'\n{member.activity.artist} - {member.activity.title}' \
                           f'\naus [{member.activity.album}]({member.activity.album_cover_url})'

            else:
                activity = f'{member.activity.name}'

            embed = discord.Embed(color=member.top_role.color.value, title=f'User-Info für {member}')
            embed.add_field(name='**Activity**', value=f'{activity}', inline=True)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: `isinstance(member.activity, Spotify)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to check the `type` of the activity - this will return the object type, which you'll then be able to compare against the `Spotify` class:

```py
elif type(member.activity) == discord.Spotify:
    # do some stuff
```

---

**References:**

- [`discord.Spotify`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Spotify)
- [`type()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/type) - Built-in method